# Rotation of rod

Tags: homework-and-exercises, newtonian-mechanics, rotational-dynamics, rigid-body-dynamics, angular-velocity

A uniform rod of length **"L"** is free to move and rotate in gravity-free space . when an impulse is given to one end of the rod perpendicular to its length, its center of mass moves with velocity **"V"**. With what angular velocity it will rotate about its center of mass ?

Comment: Please quote the book you have used. Further, did you do anything to come up with a solution yourself?

Comment: Physics for iit jee - halliday/resnick/walker. yes i did but couldnt solve it

Comment: Please explain us what you have done so far and where you got stuck - this will help make the answers to the question better adress your problem. Also, please edit clarifications into the post :)

Comment: Hi Rahul and welcome to the Physics SE! Please note that this is not a homework help site. Please see [this Meta post on asking homework questions](http://meta.physics.stackexchange.com/questions/714/how-do-i-ask-homework-questions-on-physics-stack-exchange) and [this Meta post for "check my work" problems](http://meta.physics.stackexchange.com/questions/6093/should-any-check-my-work-questions-be-made-on-topic).

Comment: sorry this is not a home work question, its just a problem from my reference book to clarify my concepts . please take the hold of answers out please !!! :)

Comment: Have you looked at a worked example in halliday/resnick/walker? Have you tried searching the internet?

Comment: i tried , And the version of the book i use is edited by another author from my country to customize it for our entrance exams, he didnt alter the texts but in the end of the chapters he added some extra  questions for the model of entrance exams. and those questions are not as popular as that of the original questions so there is no solutions online :(

Comment: Impulse = change in momentum.  Moment of impulse = change in angular momentum.  Angular momentum = moment of inertia x angular velocity. (You can take use any axis for calculating moment, but you must use the same axis for calculating MI.)

Comment: thanks  sammy for reminding me of those relations . thanks a lot.  i will try now